# Datadog: How to automate configuring Log Archives

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, datadog

How can I automate configuring Log Archives on GCP?

I can do it manually by following steps
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/archives/?tab=googlecloudstorage

I guess selenium can help this 
but I looking for a more programmatic way like Terraform or REST API

Thank you.

Comment: As of this writing, Datadog does not yet have a public API for creating/editing log archives. But they do have this in their roadmap, and you may want to reach out to support@datadoghq.com to learn more about the timeline.

Comment: Thank you! @stephenlechner
I will check the roadmap!

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if it is a recent addition, but the Datadog public API supports configuring Log Archives: https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs-archives/

You can also use tools like Terraform to configure them: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/logs_archive (it uses the Datadog API internally)